# How to simulate click on Kendoui button

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, click, simulate

Where is a problem? I fire click event and nothing happens:

```
<button id="btn_test">Test</button>
$('#btn_test').kendoButton();
var btn = $("#btn_test").data("kendoButton");
$(btn).click() // nothing happens
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggested method:

```
$(btn).trigger('click')
```

does not work again, but this one does work:

```
$('#btn_test').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use kendo object instead of jquery object:

```
btn.trigger('click')
```